# C#: Is there a way to return a reference to the selected Item in listview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

C#: Is there a way to return a reference to the selected Item in listview?

Like in the selectedindexchanged, is there a way to return the item of the index that was selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

```
myListView.Items[ myListView.SelectedIndices[ 0 ] ];
```

or

```
myListView.SelectedItems[ 0 ];
```

should work